# Fail cvinvert on Iplimage or Mat

Tags: xcode, opencv

i need use CvInvert, but i have this problem:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.type() == dst.type() && src.rows
>   == dst.cols && src.cols == dst.rows) in cvInvert, file /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_graphics_opencv/opencv/work/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/core/src/lapack.cpp, line 1738 libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

This is Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core_c.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    CvCapture* capture=cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
    IplImage* originalImg;
    cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
    cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);
    cvNamedWindow("Imagen");

    while (true) {
        originalImg=cvQueryFrame(capture);
        cvFlip(originalImg,originalImg,3);
        IplImage* Gray=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(originalImg), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
        cvCvtColor(originalImg, Gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);

        CvMat* Mat_tipo=cvCreateMat(originalImg->height, originalImg->width, CV_32F);
        CvMat* Mat_img=cvGetMat(Gray,Mat_tipo);

        CvMat* Matinvenrt=cvCreateMat(Mat_img->rows, Mat_img->cols, CV_32F);
        cvInvert(Mat_img, Matinvenrt,CV_LU);





        cvShowImage("Imagen", Mat_img);
//        imshow("imagen", img);
        cvReleaseMat(&Mat_img);

        int  id=cvWaitKey(27);
        if (id==27) break;       
    }


}
```

What happen??, Have Cvinvert a bug??

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Assertion failed (src.type() == dst.type()
```

it is clearly visible from your code that the Mat types are not the same for `Mat_img` and `Matinvert`

Comment: Mmmm dude, see the 2 CvMat's, of CV_32F type. And i try whit IplImage, and fail too.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are inverting a square matrix?
I had a similar error and was because I was trying to invert a M-N matrix.